# How to run symfony cli command with --webapp using local composer.phar?

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-cli

I run different versions of Symfony and PHP on my Mac for various apps I have to work on (sorry that our clients are so slow to get to upgrade), and I'm trying to install the LTS version of Symfony through the CLI documentation recommendations, but I'm trying to get it to use a composer.phar in the folder I run the command in... it keeps defaulting to the globally-installed one.

Sure I could just go change composer's execution path or upgrade/downgrade it temporarily whenever I want to run the cli for x version of PHP, but that's gonna drive me crazy and I'd rather see how to tell it to run a certain composer.phar file. I'm not seeing in the documentation how to do this to get the benefits of the `--webapp` option.

The documentation is weird on it anyway; I can't tell if running composer directly (as `composer.phar`) will give me the benefits of the `--webapp` option using the `symfony` command (because the composer commands are identical for 'traditional web application' and 'console application or API'):

https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications

```
# run this if you are building a traditional web application
$ symfony new my_project_directory --version=5.4 --webapp

# run this if you are building a microservice, console application or API
$ symfony new my_project_directory --version=5.4

# run this if you are building a traditional web application
$ composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"^5.4" my_project_directory
$ cd my_project_directory
$ composer require webapp

# run this if you are building a microservice, console application or API
$ composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"^5.4" my_project_directory
```

When I run the install through composer directly, I can't tell if I'm getting the benefits of the `symfony` command `--webapp` option... and I'm not seeing an option for the `symfony` command to specify to use the folder's composer.phar.

Comment: looks like flying blind ;o/ as far as I can tell, running symfony with `-f [path to composer]` might do the trick. the problem is: how will you verify that it's actually used? but better yet, symfony apparently respects the PATH env var, so if you put a directory with your composer.phar first, it'll most likely use it.

Comment: also, if I understand the code in https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/blob/fd8a7fc930882f675cdf9318272816ebfbdb5bed/local/php/executor.go correctly, symfony is defaulting to the working directory first for finding composer, unless you're providing an existing script (with different path) as the first cli argument ... then it'll use that directory the script is in ... ?

Comment: I'm dumb, I missed part of the 3rd command for the first set of composer commands that specifies to require webapp. Strangely, I could never get Symfony CLI --webapp to work, no matter which versions of PHP or composer or Symfony CLI I was using, even the latest, even for the latest Symfony. It just will not work on my Mac. Oh well. The composer commands seem to be working, though it's a mountain of information to look at.

Comment: While I'm not seeing where you're finding a description of the -f option, it does look like the Symfony CLI code is defaulting to the working directory for composer or composer.phar, but it still couldn't find webapp even with that there regardless of any versions of anything. I have no idea why it can't find webapp. That seemed to be the only problem.

Comment: the [-f option](https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/blob/fd8a7fc930882f675cdf9318272816ebfbdb5bed/local/php/executor.go#L416) is most likey meant to allow for custom scripts to somehow be executed, however, it will determine the "scriptdir" which is - as far as I can tell, [the directory searched first](https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/blob/fd8a7fc930882f675cdf9318272816ebfbdb5bed/local/php/executor.go#L274), before falling back to the default "findComposer" method. however, -f is probably not applicable to your use case ;o/ actually just a shot in the dark.

Comment: I'm still not seeing where you're seeing the `-f` option documented. Just in the code...?

Comment: yeah, it's absolutely in the code only. haven't looked anywhere else. I'm mostly sorry for even bringing it up, since it doesn't appear to help ;o/

Answer (score 0):

I had to cheat a little bit: I installed the latest composer using the instructions here to a composer.phar file:

https://getcomposer.org/download/

I then created a console alias like `php composer.phar`, ran the Symfony create composer command with that alias, which created the symfony-5 folder no problem, then I copied the composer.phar file to the new folder and run the alias for any other composer commands, like with `require webapp`, which is working! Kind of nice to freeze a version of composer for any similar repos.

Maybe not the best answer, but it's working.

Also I discovered that I could just run `composer self-update` to get the latest version, which worked, then `composer self-update [whatever version number]` to get back to one I need that works with other repos (since certain version ranges just do not work with certain version ranges of PHP). Annoying, but functional.

Ultimately I think moving forward, it's best to make a copy of composer.phar at a compatible version range for your older PHP apps, depending on their versions, and use those in an alias, rather than totally rely on a global composer version, which has proven not completely workable for my work.